# Spring Batch Processor Deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Boot application that runs a Spring Batch Processor on receiving a request. The processor step involves calling multiple APIs. The database is SQL Server. Following are the details about the job

- No of partitions - 10 - each reading 2000 records from database table
- Task Executor - max pool size - 1000
- Task Executor - core pool size -500
- Task Executor - queue capacity - 1000
- Write chunk size - 100

There is only one job running at one point of time.

I am using Spring Data JPA to save list of Hibernate entities. Inserting results into database with multiple partitions causes deadlocks.

Any help in figuring out the issue will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.